# TextBox formating, I know this has been talked about I could not find my answer to custom formatting

Tags: c#, windows-8, textbox, microsoft-metro, currency

Is it possible to type a number like 100 into a textbox that is formatted with {0:C} and have the output be $1.00? Also have the textbox only except numbers?  I found this link but it does not give me exactly what I am looking for [XAML Metro Numeric only TextBox](http://blog.evanrosebrook.com/2012/09/xaml-metro-style-numeric-only-currency.html).  This may not be possible.  The issue is that with the link above when I type in 350 it turns it into $350.00 and since its a number only I can not put in a decimal point, I would like a number only with a decimal point to do 3.5 to be $3.50

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: couldn't you do this quite simply by listening to the `onBlur`-event and reformatting the input then? The same could be done for the `Focused`-event, removing dollar signs and what else you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

The sample you linked to gets you 95% of the way there. You could change the code to allow for decimal place like this:

```
if (!(key >= '0' && key <= '9') && (key != '.'))
```

Alternatively you could divide the entire amount by 100 to turn 350 into 3.5.

```
if(Decimal.TryParse(textBox.Text.Trim(), NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, out value))
        {
            value = value / 100;
            textBox.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", value);
        }
```

Dev support, design support and more awesome goodness on the way: http://bit.ly/winappsupport